# Users who edit questions don't always seems to answer. Why is that the case?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

If I misspell something in a question, someone will usually come in and edit it immediately. But that buddy will not always answer the question.

Why is that so?

Comment: Most people know how to fix spelling and grammar. Not as many know the answer to a specific question. Is that so strange?

Comment: @Lucifer: why? it's not about a specific question and I think most of us have seen that often enough (I personally have *done* that often enough).

Comment: Sigh...really @matt? ;) P.s. please note that I'm not answering your question BalluSingh.

Comment: @Bart: Aww, come on buddy :(.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because they may not have the time? Or they want to focus on editing? Or they don't know the answer? The last one is rather common -- one need not be able to answer a question to fix grammar.

This is all volunteer work, they can be involved as much as they want. Stack Overflow is not your personal help assistant. Don't expect people to answer any question you ask just because they have seen the question.

Answer (score 14):

Just because I can edit your question doesn't mean I know the answer to it.

Comment: I never said it was a waste of my time. Don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @BalluSingh it isn't wasting time editing poor spelling and grammar. By editing it, it is improving the standard of the question.

Comment: @BalluSingh: it's not wasted time. For one a well-written question is easier to understand and answer. And second, keep in mind that the original author of the question is *one of many people* who will read the answers. And if the question is well-written, then it's easier to find if you have a similar problem.

Comment: @BalluSingh: Editing makes it easy for others to answer. You're getting free help here, don't be rude about it.

Comment: Fixing the question grammatically may help others better understand the question and therefore make it more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @BalluSingh I'm not wasting my time. I really really (did I mention really?) get annoyed by poorly written/formatted posts. And correcting them is not only helpful to the author, but makes me happy as well. It's a win-win situation.

Comment: @Bart yes you mentioned **really**, don't worry.

Answer (score 7):

Knowing how to correct grammar and spelling has no relevance to a person's knowledge of a particular subject matter, unless the question's subject matter is grammar and spelling.

Comment: In which case it should DEFINITELY be closed as off-topic. :D