# Waiting for review count for spam/offensive flags

Tags: feature-request, flags

Flags are treated differently between spam/offensive flags and other flags. ie, for normal/common flags we are having the count of waiting for review, but for spam/offensive flags we don't have that count.

My flag count history.

[image]

If we show the waiting for review count for spam/offensive flags,then only a user can know either his/her flag will be reviewed or not and those flags will not be left [unhandled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175768/what-is-the-result-of-my-spam-flag).

Comment: Yes, spam/offensive flags handles on highest priority basis.