# Count for spam flags waiting for review misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam, flags, information-display

I flagged a post as spam. It is showing waiting for review. But, under moderator attention flags like below,

[image]

Spam flag will also be handled by moderators. But, we have separate section for spam flags. Previously, [we don't have waiting for review count for spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179545/waiting-for-review-count-for-spam-offensive-flags). Now it is showing the count, but in wrong place. Please fix this issue.

Comment: Normally they shouldn't be shown at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this was missed.

The waiting for review status shouldn't be shown for spam flags.

Fixed in the next build.