# "*older flags were not recorded helpful/declined" message only displayed in meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, flags

I'm seeing a message(*older flags were not recorded helpful/declined) below the flagging history on meta site.

[image]

It reveals that if a [flag got unhandled due to deletion or some other reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175768/what-is-the-result-of-my-spam-flag) and became older, then it will not be added as either helpful or declined/disputed.

But, this message is only shown in meta Stack Overflow. I can't find it in any of the SE sites.
Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: It is not showing in my flag summary...

Comment: A box probably takes less effort than those strange lines... Plus, opaque boxes are hard to see through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When any of your flag marked as a *none* first time then only that message is shown. So that means none of your flags in Stack Overflow is marked as *none*.

Comment: It shouldn't really show for things marked none recently though since that message refers to flags raised during the time before flag weights when there was never a recorded outcome.

Comment: @Flexo It does show on my [SO] flagging summary, but I only joined when flag weight was long established (and soon to be hidden). Doesn't seem to work as intended then.