# Flagged post status is set to "eventinvalidated" in my flagging history

Tags: support, flags

I flagged a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727189/my-localhost-is-not-running) yesterday as a duplicated question and now its status is set to **eventinvalidated**. I can see this in my Flagging History section.

I'm not sure I understand what it means since the post is still there and has not been deleted. It's the first time I have seen this status.

Could someone enlighten me about that?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The flag *was* invalidated, but not *declined*, it doesn't count against you. This particular flag result reason exists because:

- All flags are kept in the system, even ones that are impossible to resolve or act upon (we don't hard delete much of anything here)
- The system needs to be able to resolve them when impossible scenarios (like the target duplicate being deleted) happen.

If this weren't the case, we'd have the following options:

1. Automatically mark the flag as helpful (bad, as many flags *aren't* helpful)
2. Just delete the flag (bad, as people would wonder where their flag went)
3. Nullify the flag like this, in a way that doesn't count for or against you

It's not anything you need to worry about. It's just a plug that fills a gap when a scenario sets up that makes your flag impossible to resolve as helpful or unhelpful. The flag *is* in its final state - it's not lingering, it's fully resolved. We should make this more obvious on the flag summary.

The reason has since been modified to say "removed during a deletion" instead of "eventinvalidated" to make this more clear.

Comment: Also, is such a flag counted as "disputed"? If not then which of the counters?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No - It's just nullified. It's in the system to remain in your history but is neither helpful, disputed, or unhelpful (declined), those are three totally different resolution types in the DB. Think of it like garbage collection (not to imply the flag was garbage, more the principle).

Comment: Fair enough, just nitpicking now - why not add "X invalidated" below "moderator attention flags", same way there is count for everything else? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd because that isn't _nearly_ cryptic enough and I value my job security.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification. Correct me if I am wrong but I think I have now understood why I can also see on my flag history page [*older flags were not recorded helpful/declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182285/older-flags-were-not-recorded-helpful-declined-message-only-displayed-in-meta)